# Limitation of having 9 workspaces with 3 monitors solution - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, workspaces

**Problem:**
I have a stationary computer with ubuntu linux 18.04. 3 monitors connected and I can have maximum 9 workspaces. Even if I set "Gnome tweak tool" to 12 workspaces it shows only 9 workspaces. Note! The left/right monitor shows 12 workspaces.

**Wanted behaviour**: 
To set workspaces to more then 9 monitors, and that both center screen and side monitors show icon for the amount of screens.

**Installations/Packages implemented:**

(The packages are required but does not solve the problem with limit maximum 9 workspaces)

- Gnome tweaks tool - To have extra workspaces.
- Gnoe workspace grid -
- Multi monitor add-on - to have workspaces visible on left/right screens.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/

Comment: I don't see. I was able to set 20 fixed workspaces that accordingly all show up as tiny thumbnails in the overview. This however may be  related to the fact you have a multi-monitor setup, or to the multi-monitors extension.

Comment: @vanadium. I update the title to clarify that it is a 3-monitor-solution.

Comment: @pomsky I updated the question. The packages are a requirement to extend amount of monitors and have workspace visible on the 2nd/3rd monitor. But packages does not solve the problem of limitation 9 workspace.

Answer (score 0):

By updating "multi monitors add-on" and "Gnome workspace grid" it is now possible in "workspace grid" to set up to 36 workspaces.